# How to display selected item from "select" to "text field" in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm develop simple Spring boot app using Thymeleaf and want to display selected "user" from Combobox1 at the "userName" text field. How i can made it?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Добавить цитату</title>
</head>
<body>
<form th:action="@{/addQuote}"
  th:object="${personForm}" method="POST">
<p><b>Имя</b><br>
<div>
    <input name = "userName" type="text" size="38" th:field="*{name}" >
    <a style="position:fixed;left:0px;top:0px;margin: 0;border-width:0;z- 
index:255"></a>
</div>
<textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="6" th:field="*{text}"  >
</textarea>
<p><input type="reset" value="Отменить">
    <input type="submit" value="+"></p>
<select name="Combobox1" size="1" id="Combobox1"
      style="position:absolute;left:17%;top:4%;width:199px;height:20px;z- 
index:3;" >
    <option th:each="user : ${users}"
            th:value="${user}"
            th:utext="${user}"/>
 </select>
</form>
<div th:if="${errorMessage}" th:utext="${errorMessage}"
 style="color:red;font-style:italic;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: 
Add Id in your userName input tag

```
<input id="userName" name = "userName" type="text" size="38" th:field="*{name}" />
```

Add script

```
<script>
 function check() {
     document.getElementById("userName").value=document.getElementById("Combobox1").value;
    } 
 </script>
```

Call script function

```
 <select id="Combobox1"  onChange="check();">
```

Option2:

Another option with Jquery

```
$(function() { 
  $("#Combobox1").on("change",function() { 
  alert();
    $("#userName").val($(this).val()); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: @Aleksey : Welcome. Please question as answered